# OpenShift SSL cipher preferences configuration

Tags: ssl, openshift

I have a question regarding the configuration of SSL preferences on OpenShift.
As far I know, the SSL termination in OpenShift is executed on the HAproxy, which serves as reverse proxy to route to user gears.

Is there a possibility, to configure the SSL preferences, to use user specific order of prefered ciphers, and also to turn off some versions of SSL/TLS as it is possible for instance in tomcat, or is the SSL cipher and versions configuration platform specific and can't be changed by user?